# How to do a search with EF CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Currently, to do a search using EF CodeFirst and a repository pattern, based on user input to multiple text boxes on an mvc search view/page, I do something like the following:

```
    public PagedList<Entity1> PlayerUserSearch(Entity1SearchParameters searchParameters, int? pageSize, int? startEntity, Func<Entity1, object> sortOrder, bool sortDesc)
    {
        IQueryable<Entity1> query = from entities in this.DataContext.Entity1s.Include("Entity2List")
                                    where entities.Entity2List.Any()
                                    select entities;

        if (searchParameters.Entity2PrimaryKeyId.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(e => e.Id == searchParameters.Entity2PrimaryKeyId.Value);

        if (searchParameters.HasStats.HasValue)
        {
            if (searchParameters.HasStats.Value)
                query = query.Where(u => u.Entity2List.Any(e => e.Stat != null));
            else
                query = query.Where(u => u.Entity2List.Any(e => e.Stat == null));
        }

        if (searchParameters.Entity2OtherField.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(u => u.Entity2List.Any(e => e.Event.Entity2OtherField == searchParameters.Entity2OtherField));

        if (searchParameters.Entity2OtherField2.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(u => u.Entity2List.Any(e => e.Event.Entity2OtherField2 == searchParameters.Entity2OtherField2));

        if (searchParameters.Active.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(e => e.Active == searchParameters.Active.Value);

        return this.GetPageByStartEntity(pageSize.Value, startEntity.Value, query, sortOrder, sortDesc);
    }
```

The problem with this is that for every time I add on another where that checks the child of Entity1 (Entity2) for a certain field, it takes on a new " AND EXISTS" clause to the sql statement generated, so that it is doing an exists and checking table Entity2 all over again for every different field checked, rather than doing a single EXISTS on Entity in the query, and checking all fields I tacked on to the query (i.e. EntityOtherField1 and EntityOtherField2).  I haven't been able to find a better way to do a search based on user inputs than constantly checking for the input being there (add to the search parameters)) and then tacking on a new where to the current query.  Can anyone tell me if there is a better way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is using Specification Pattern.

```
var spec = new specification<Entity2>(s => true);
if (searchParameters.HasStats.Value)
{
    spec = spec.And(e => e.Stat != null);
}

if (searchParameters.Entity2OtherField2.HasValue)
{
        spec = spec.And(e => e.Event.Entity2OtherField2 == searchParameters.Entity2OtherField2);
}

query = query.Where(u => u.Entity2List.Any(spec));
```

Or I believe you can make it more standard by separating the filter logic and using `spec.IsStatisfiedBy` method.
A good framework for repository/specification implemetation on Entity Framework can be found [here](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/).

Comment: I think the bigger issue I may be having is that using an Include to make sure Entity2 gets returned conflicts with having an Any (exists) on the same entity/table.  ...so even if I restrict what I am looking for by using the Any on that list of Entity2 children, having the Include still causes a join to that table, which will join to all records in that table, even though I don't want it to.  How can I get it so that instead of doing an exists from using Any, to just adding those parameter checks to the current clause instead of to an exists?